# Was Australia ever attacked during WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, australia

Being European, I know history of World War II from Europe's perspective (and mainly with focus on Czechoslovakia).

So:

**Was a land belonging to Australia ever attacked during WW2?**

For scope of question, it does not to be mainland, but if there are islands belonging to Australia, that applies to (Pearl Harbour and USA example).

And if yes, what was the most important battle?

Comment: Yes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_raids_on_Australia,_1942%E2%80%9343

Comment: You need to watch the movie [Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia_(2008_film))! (It has the Japanese attack on Darwin in it)

Comment: There's actually a wikipedia article on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attacks_on_Australia_during_World_War_II

Comment: Welcome to the site; I regret that your first question was closed, but [ask] establishes the community standard that we close any question that can be answered by wikipedia; I think your question was on the edge - the first two links weren't obvious topics to search, but the third link was.  If those wikipedia pages don't answer your underlying question, please ask another, and please feel free to answer other questions.

Comment: Quite apart from the attacks on Darwin, the Japanese invaded Papua New Guinea, an area administered by Australia. They also occupied the western part of the same island, then part of the Netherlands East Indies. A long campaign was fought from late 1942 to evict the Japanese from the territory. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Guinea_campaign

Comment: Also, Japanese mini subs managed to launch an attack in Sydney harbour where an number of ships and ferries were hit with torpedoes. The Japanese not only bombed Darwin but other location in the Northern Territory as well as in north western Western Australia.

Comment: While the Japanese didn't appear to be planning one, before Coral Sea and Midway the Australians certainly feared attack. Didn't transpire, just another interesting wiki page. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_Japanese_invasion_of_Australia_during_World_War_II    in fact this was the only Japanese land incursion https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimberley_(Western_Australia):